# How can i go to delegate class from UIViewController class in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I have created the one privite delegate class. I want to call this delegate class when click on button in my `UIViewController` class. Once please give me the solution. I am writing the Code here Once plz observe this.

```
-(IBAction)gotoDailPad:(id)sender{
    FirstViewApplication *appDelegate = (FirstViewApplication *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

Comment: You don't. There's almost no reason to do this.,

Answer (score 0):

To access the app delegate, you have it right: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`.

Now to access a method or member of the delegate, *make sure it is exposed in the header* (.h) file. For instance, if you wanted to call a method implemented in the implementation (.m) file, declare it in the .h file:

in `AppDelegate.h`

`-(int) getCurrentAppID;`

in `AppDelegate.m`

`-(int) getCurrentAppID { return 0; }`

That's all there is to it... there is nothing "special" about the app delegate in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

better if u import viewController in your delegate, as per common standerd

```
#import "viewControler.h"
```

in delegate class

- Delegate class is start up of an app so advised to not to go backward at root

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.firstViewController someMethod]
```